# Is surface Tension a Scalar, Vector or a Tensor (2nd order or above)?

Tags: forces, terminology, vectors, surface-tension

I am a bit confused regarding the nature of surface tension. Now, it can be defined as energy (E) per unit area (A). This basically means that surface tension (T) relates a scalar (energy E) with a vector (area A) as
$$E = TA$$
So, surface tension cannot be a scalar I guess.

Another definition of surface tension is force (F) per unit length (l), here length (l) is just the magnitude so a scalar. This means surface tension (T) relates a vector (force F) to a scalar (length l) as
$$F = Tl$$
which kind of means , $T$ should be a vector. But again it does not have a specific direction.

Any ideas in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is a scalar. Consider generic case - some $p$-surface. It's $p$-volume is something like
$$
\int d^{p} \xi \sqrt{\det g (x(\xi))}
$$ 
Where $g$ is a induced metric on the surface, $\xi$ are the coordinates on hypersurface, and the integration is over the hypersurface. In the case $p = 1$ you have some curve in the space, and for $p = 2$ some membrane, surface in common sense.

This quantity is already a scalar, however, to match the dimensions - tension $T$ must have proper units. $T$ multiplies the whole integral not the local element of length(area).

$$
[E] = length^{-1}, \ [Vol_{p}] = length^{p} \Rightarrow [T] = length^{-p-1}
$$